# SQL: how to add restriction to table variable?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

How to add restriction(narrow down) to a table variable? For example,

```
select * from Employee e 
where (e.type=1 and e.salary>100) and 
      (e.type=1 and e.age>20) or 
      (e.type=1 and e.city='Foo')
```

There are many `e.type=1`. For this particular example, it can be simplified.
In general, can it be replaced with a new table variable(identifier)? For example,

```
select * from Employee e 
LEFT join (select e.* where e.type=1) g
where g.salary>100 and g.age>20 or g.city='FOO'
```

MySQL error: unknown table e.

### UPDATE

How about the following?

```
select * from Employee e 
LEFT join (select * from Employee em) as g on (g.id=e.id and e.type=1)
where g.salary>100 and g.age>20 or g.city='FOO'
```

How about the performance with a join with such subquery? If the database is smart enough, it should take no time to evaluate the dynamic join table(subquery) since the result of the join condition (on) is the same row. Is this true for popular databases such as Mysql, oracle, SQL server, sqlite, etc.?

Comment: If the database is smart it will have not problem with the condition.  A join here adds nothing but the overhead of the join. So small overhead - still going the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see join as a solution.
This is a simplified version of your query.

```
select * 
from Employee e 
where e.type = 1 
  and e.salary > 10 
  and (e.age > 20 or e.city = 'Foo')
```

Comment: thanks. updated with new SQL, but not sure about the join performance?

Comment: @Sunnyday How can a join to a condition be better than just searching on the condition?   All you have done is ADD the overhead of the join.  The where invalidate the left.  I don't know what you are thinking but you are think wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Or, write it as:

```
select e.* 
from Employee e 
where e.type = 1 and
      (e.salary > 100 or e.age > 20 or e.city = 'Foo');
```

A `join` would not be appropriate for this logic at all.  A `join` without an `on` clause is a broken query (MySQL does allow it under some circumstances, but almost no other database does).

Comment: thanks. updated with new SQL, but not sure about the join performance?